# Почему typescript ругается на new Router в express?

Tags: typescript, express

new Router() подчеркнут и при наведении такая ошибка тайпскрипта
TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

```js
import {Router} from "express";
import NoteController from "../repositories/NoteController";

const notesRouter = new Router()

notesRouter.get('/notes/stats', NoteController.getStats)

notesRouter.get('/notes', NoteController.getAll)

notesRouter.get('/notes/:id', NoteController.getOne)

notesRouter.put('/notes/archive/:id', NoteController.archive)

notesRouter.put('/notes/unarchive/:id', NoteController.unarchive)

notesRouter.post('/notes', NoteController.create)

notesRouter.put('/notes/:id', NoteController.update)

notesRouter.delete('/notes/:id', NoteController.delete)

export default notesRouter;
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `new Router()`? Это же действительно не конструктор. `const notesRouter = Router()` https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router

Comment: @AlexeyTen, почему не ответом?

Answer (score 1):

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router

`Router` это не класс (и не конструктор), так что Typescript ругается вполне по делу.

Просто вызывайте функцию:

```
const notesRouter = Router();
```